# Python password protection code not writing to file

Tags: python

I have attempted to get this code working in Python 3.5.1 but I am having problems with it not writing the hashed password and username to the file specified. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
import sys
import hashlib
import getpass

def main():

print ('\nUser & Password Storage Program v.01\n')

if input('The file will be modieifed if it exists.\nDo you wish to continue (Y/N): ') not in ('Y','y'):
    sys.exit('\nChanges were not recorded\n')

user_name = input(str('Please Enter a User Name: '))
pwdinput = input("Now enter a password:").encode('utf-8')
password = hashlib.sha224(pwdinput).hexdigest()

try:
    f = open(passfile.txt,'a+')
    f.write(user_name + '\n')
    f.write(password + '\n')
    f.close()
except:
    sys.exit('There was a problem writing to the file!')

print ('\nPassword safely stored in passfile.txt.\n')       

main()
```

Comment: You should add `except BaseException as e:` and print out the exception code. So you can output any kind of exception without ignoring them.

Comment: Why do you explicitly swallow all errors (`except:`)? Isn't allowing an app to show you **what an error is** more likely to help you to solve your problem?

Comment: `f = open(passfile.txt,'a+')` is incorrect. You probably need quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a variable called `passfile.txt`, and that is making the `open` call fail. It would be correctly opening the file if you surrounded it in quotes, like `'passfile.txt'`

The reason this syntax error isn't obvious is because you have a catch all, and your program will just print 'There was a problem writing to the file!' instead.

Rather than catch all exceptions using `except:`, use the syntax `except IOError:`, as that will be thrown whenever there is an actual error in writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your open() function is taking an object as a parameter, but you probably meant to use it as a string.

Also, you generally should use a `with` block when opening files.

```
try:
    with open("passfile.txt",'a+') as f:
        f.write("{}\n{}\n".format(user_name, password))
except Exception as e: # Use other exceptions for more accurate results
    sys.exit('There was a problem writing to the file!\nError: {}'.format(str(e)))
```